# How to add "close (pull down) indicator (line)" above the search field in iOS 13

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, ios13

How to add the "pull down" indicator above search in iOS 13 like it made in map app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add it manually.

Just drag and drop a UIView, give it a gray background and constraints like the following.

[image]

You also might want to check this [pod](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley) in case you want to create a pull-up menu just like the Maps app. In fact their demo app is a Map application.

Here's their demo:

[image: Pulley Preview]